# how to start activity from background service in android Q os, without click 'Allow background activity starts' from settings of developer option?

Tags: android, privacy, restriction, background-service, android-10.0

i want to start activity from background service in Android Q OS But it will give me message 'Background activity start from com.test.testandroidapp blocked.See g.co/dev/bgblock'.

According following link:
https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/background-activity-starts.
Disable restrictions by turning on the Allow background activity starts developer option.But what is the alternate option of 'Allow background activity' without enable this option from settings of 'Developer Option'.

Comment: Would be much better If you post the code and also `logcat` :)

Comment: Did you try with the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission maybe?

Comment: @Tanasis `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` is not available in Android GO.

Comment: @Priya Lalani did you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Please try this -

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

First, two take-ups run time permission for android 10.